# How can I comment out my Ruby return values with something like "# =>"?

Tags: ruby, comments, return-value, read-eval-print-loop

Having just started with Ruby and while following a tutorial, the result was shown as:

```
a + b # => 3
```

I have never seen such a possibility; that seems so handy! Could you please tell me what it is? is it proprietary or is it for everyone?

Comment: thank you both for answering, what i meant was: in this tutorial, that expression was shown on _any_ exercise (maybe 100?), maybe a lot to 'type' '# =>'. i thought that might be a program or plugin that would provide this (automatic calculation?), if so, which one?

Comment: if anyone is new also :) please look down further, that is a feature to download in github.

Comment: Yes, it's just a comment, beginning with the character following `#`. `=>`  generally means "the value returned by the expression is the following".  On the other hand, it you had `puts 'hi'` (which returns `nil`), you'll sometimes see `puts 'hi' #=> 'hi'`, meaning `hi` is printed. (I prefer something different, maybe `# hi` or `#-> hi`, but am not fussy.)  You'll see both `# =>` and `#=>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Josh Cheek's [seeing is believing](https://github.com/JoshCheek/seeing_is_believing). Apparently you can run it over your code, or it can be integrated in several editors.

Comment: I think all the answers to this question should be comments, but I appreciate your reference to "seeing is believing" (great name!). I had not heard of it before, but it looks interesting.

Comment: Great and thank you! That's an amazing thing. Sorry, do not have enough reputation to make 'upvote'

Answer (score 0):

### Reconfigure Your REPL

The `#` symbol is a comment in Ruby. By default, most Ruby REPLs (e.g. [irb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html) or [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry)) will use `=>` to prefix the return value of your last expression.

In IRB, you can modify this prefix so that each return value is prefixed by a different string. You can do this through the IRB::Context#return_format method on your *conf* instance. For example:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> conf.return_format = "#=> %s\n"
#=> "#=> %s\n"
irb(main):002:0> 1 + 2
#=> 3
```

More permanent changes would have to be made in your [IRB configuration file](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Configuration) by [customizing the prompt](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Customizing+the+IRB+Prompt) through the `IRB.conf[:PROMPT]` [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html) and then setting `IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE]` to your custom prompt, but in my opinion the solution above is simpler even though you have to run it within the current REPL session rather than saving it as a default.